# Change Kendo UI Timepicker Highlighted Text Color

Tags: html, css, sass, kendo-ui, kendo-timepicker

How we can change the highlighted text color area in kendo ui time picker.

KENDO UI TIMEPICKER - https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dateinputs/timepicker/

As you see in this image, `10:30 AM` is the highlighted area. I want to change the color of that time to `red`.

I did lots of research but didn't find any solution for this, i saw the html bellow somewhat it look like.

[image]

Found that if we change color of class `<span class="k-time-highlight"></span>` only background changes not text.
[image]

This link is extracted code - https://silver-ranique-14.tiiny.site/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.k-time-highlight` only references a span that sits on top of the items. The DOM that actually gets created when you open the TimePicker is (truncated for brevity):

- `<kendo-popup>`

  - `<div class="k-popup">`

    - `<kendo-timeselector>`

      - `<k-time-list-container>`

        - `<span class="k-time-highlight">` (the overlay that indicates selected item)
        - `<div class="k-time-list-wrapper">` (for hours)
        - `<div class="k-time-separator">` (separator)
        - `<div class="k-time-list-wrapper">` (for minutes)
        - `<div class="k-time-separator">` (separator)
        - `<div class="k-time-list-wrapper">` (for AM/PM)

And each `k-time-list-wrapper` has the following:

- `<kendo-timelist>`

  - `<kendo-virtualization>`

    - `<ul>`

      - `<li class="k-item">` (repeated for each value, e.g. hours 1 - 23)

Unfortunately, I don't think you're able to style the `<li class="k-item">` that appears under the `<span class="k-time-highlight">` because there is no context that indicates when it is under the overlay.